# How to avoid byte quoted column headers when reading redshift data with pg8000

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, pg8000

I'm loading some redshift data in pandas via pg8000:

```
>>>> df = pd.read_sql(sql_text, pg8000_cnx)
```

`pg8000_cnx` is a connection object to a redshift database. I always get columns that are byte quoted, ex:

```
>>> df.columns
Index([b'column_',
       b'column_2',
       ...
       b'column_n'],
       dtype='object', length=142)
```

I know I can use `.decode('utf-8')` and some list comprehension to convert the columns back to string, but I was trying to have them loaded in string format from redshift itself. Tried playing with different `CLIENT_ENCODING` settings with the pg8000 cursor, but still get byte quoted columns in the pandas df.

```
import pg8000
conn = pg8000.connect(**db_details)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8'")
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchone()
# load df here
```

Is there some redshift or pg8000 option I am missing that would load the column headers in utf-8 decoded strings from the db connection object itself?

Comment: why are you using pg8000? can you test same using a more defacto library such as Psycopg2?

Comment: `pg8000` is a perfectly valid choice and is useful in scenarios where you want to reduce the number of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [fixed](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#version-1-16-6-2020-10-10) in pg8000 1.16.6, so upgrading to the latest version should solve the problem.

So from verion 1.16.6 pg8000 returns column names as `str` rather than `bytes`.